# how to use linprog to calculate f(x) with a constant in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I know the linprog can deal with questions like this

```
Find x that minimizes

f(x) = –5x1 – 4x2 –6x3,

subject to

x1 – x2 + x3 ≤ 20
3x1 + 2x2 + 4x3 ≤ 42
3x1 + 2x2 ≤ 30
0 ≤ x1, 0 ≤ x2, 0 ≤ x3.
```

However, if I add a constant to f(x) so that change it into something like f(x) = -5x1 -4x2  + 2, it seems that the linprog can't work it out. Could anybody please give me any ideas about how to deal with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

f(x) = -5x1 -4x2 - 6x3 + 2 , suppose g(x)= -5x1 -4x2 - 6x3 , f(x) can  be formalized as f(x) = g(x) +2 ,it is obvious that min(f(x)) = min(g(x)) +2 , so  minimize g(x) instead